# What process is using my HD on startup?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, process-explorer

The boot-up sequence for my work PC (running XP 32) takes nearly a half hour to complete.  It's an older machine and the HD is encrypted so I understand why it is slow.  What I don't understand is what happens in the last 10 minutes when my HD light is on (and I can hear it spinning and the PC is very unresponsive) but no activity shows up in the Process Explorer I/O Bytes section.  I'd expect to see some activity there.

Is there another way to determine what process is utilizing my HD?

Comment: Try using Microsoft's Bootvis (I think you can download it from MajorGeeks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also look into Soluto, I assume it does a similar thing like Bootvis, but I've found it helpful at times: [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/)